# Tests pass locally but fail in azure devops

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, mstest

We have several tests that have been running OK for years, ca. 2 days ago they started failing.

I have isolated the problem to this code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void TestException()
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
```

This runs OK locally but fails in Azure Devops, with the error:

> Test method TestException threw exception:
> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Edit:

The problem is related to the project type.

- We have some projects where the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll is via a nuget package. In these projects the test fails on the devops server
- We have some projects where the reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll is via project references. In these projects the test runs OK on the devops server

Comment: and what happens when you run it locally? Do you have other tests running in some background thread? other test cases also can cause issue

Comment: That can't possibly be your real code can it? If it is...remove it because that's a bit of a pointless test. If it's not your real code, then we need your real code to tell what's wrong.

Comment: @viveknuna locally I use Visual Studio to run the test

Comment: @gilliduck you are correct this is not "real" code. But it is the simplest code that reproduces the error

Comment: So you're confirming that the exact code above, when run locally passes the test, but when run through Azure Devops fails the test?

Comment: Does DevOps run the same Test Runner? In the same Version? Seems like it ignores the annotation.

Comment: @gilliduck yes that is exactly the problem. And that it was fine in Azure Devops untill about 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue today, this isn't a fix but here was my workaround to get the tests passing correctly

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestException()
{
    Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(() =>
        throw new ArgumentException()
    );
}
```